# SpeechRecognition doesn´t work in Python (Raspberry Pi 4). I get except in try/except

Tags: python, exception, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi4

As I say in the title I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 and Thonny Python IDE. My code is simple and I've seen the same script everywhere. However, it doesn´t work for me.

Btw, I have Python 3.7.3.

I need your help!!! Please and thank you!! :))

```
import speech_recognition as sr

nombre = "broder"
listener = sr.Recognizer()

def listen():
    print("Funciona?")
    rec = ''
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            
            pc = listener.listen(sr.Microphone())
            rec = listener.recognize_google(pc)
            #Todo a minúscula, xsiaca
            rec = rec.lower()
            print("Síiiii")
            #if nombre in rec:
            #rec = rec.replace(nombre, '')
    except:
        print("Qué va")
        rec = ''
    return rec


def run_broder():
    rec = listen()
    print(rec)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_broder()
```

The output is

> Funciona?
> Qué va

Comment: You're handling errors very poorly. Don't use `except:`, then throw away the error. You're discarding all useful information. Either get rid of the `try` altogether, or print out the error inside the `except`. Also, specify the **precise error** that you're expecting to handle.

Comment: Use something like `except Exception as e: logging.exception(e)` to debug your code and see which exception is raised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `speech_recognition` lib. But it looks strange to me that you create an instance of `sr.Microphone()` as context-manager, never use `source`, but create  a new instance in `pc = listener.listen(sr.Microphone())`.

Comment: Sven Eberth I copied that parte of another code. Furthermore, I've check that also. Thank you anyway

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob. I have done print (exception) and the output is "Could not find PyAudio, check installation"

Comment: So, im going to install that. Thank you everybody

Comment: People, sorry I'm late. The code final works. However, when I run I have that as output:                                                                   "ck JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock"